# Ruby + OOP: Is it okay that my subclasses expect different data types for a @shipping_address IV?

Tags: ruby, oop

Is it bad practice for my instance variable in my subclasses to be of different types? Or is this part of the beauty of ruby and dynamic typing?

Ex:

I have a superclass `UpsShipping` which has an instance variable `@shipping_method`

This is my first subclass:

```
class UpsShippingQuote < UpsShipping

  def ship_to
    {
      "CompanyName" => shipping_address.company, #<-- expects an object that responds to company, etc
      "AttentionName" => shipping_address.name,
      "PhoneNumber" => shipping_address.phone,
      "Address" => recipient_address,
      "ResidentialAddress" => nil
    }
  end

  def recipient_address
    {
      "AddressLine1" => shipping_address.address,
      "AddressLine2" => shipping_address.address_2,
      "City" => shipping_address.city,
      "StateProvinceCode" => shipping_address.state.code,
      "CountryCode" => 'US',
      "PostalCode" => shipping_address.postal_code
    }
  end
```

and a 2nd subclass:

```
class UpsShippingEstimator < UpsShipping

  def ship_to
    {
      "CompanyName" => "Test",
      "AttentionName" => "Test",
      "PhoneNumber" => "1231231234",
      "Address" => recipient_address,
      "ResidentialAddress" => nil
    }
  end

  def recipient_address
    {
      "AddressLine1" => "Test",
      "City" => shipping_address['city'], #<-- Expects a hash
      "StateProvinceCode" => shipping_address['state'],
      "CountryCode" => 'US',
      "PostalCode" => shipping_address['zip_code']
    }
  end
```

So in `UpsShippingQuote`, it expects the `shipping_method` to be an instance of my `Address` model, but in `UpsShippingEstimator`, it expects the `shipping_method` to be an instance of a hash.

Is this okay? Or is this a code smell that I'm doing inheritance wrong? Or perhaps I'm doing it properly because I'm taking advantage of dynamic typing?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should only accept a hash or something that acts like a hash. This is an interface you can give others.

Objects are a way to encapsulate knowledge so you can explain it better to others. You can't document the object if it's children takes different parameters.

On the other hand, you can use a hash as an interface:

```
class UpsShippingQuote < UpsShipping

  def ship_to
    {
      "CompanyName" => shipping_address['company'], #<-- expects an object that responds to company, etc
      "AttentionName" => shipping_address.['name'],
      "PhoneNumber" => shipping_address.['phone'],
      "Address" => recipient_address,
      "ResidentialAddress" => nil
    }
  end

end
```

This will work with `ActiveRecord`, but you can enable this behavior also for other ruby classes with the method:

```
def [] attribute
  public_send(attribute)
end
```

And that should make any Ruby class quack as a hash.